# About telescope load

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

I am using planewave CDK24 Telescope. The focuser I am using is IRF90 which has maximum load capacity of 18 kg. The load that I am going to attach is 14 kg. Is this alright to attach this weight?
Is there any rule or reference in telescope and astronomy community, on the permissible weight of the load given the max load capacity of the focuser which is 18 kg in this situation.

Comment: Not sure "space-telescope" is an appropriate tag here.

Comment: Not quite clear.  The calculated load capacity is 18 kg, and you plan to accommodate 14 kg.  Are there any reasons for concern?

Comment: Dear Dtn, The concern is that if the payload weight is close to the max load capacity of the focuser, will it impact the performance of the telescope in the long run? Can it strain  the motor of the mount. My payload is optics and with this mass, can it cause beamline deflection? Is there any guideline on this?

Comment: what mount are you putting it on?